# Generic Graph Library

Tags: c++, c++11, graph

I've been working on a generic graph library for a while now, in a bit of an off and on fashion. I realise that `boost::graph` exists, but it is a complex library that allows the user a huge amount of customisation. I have gone for a different approach; I constrain the library user much more, but this (hopefully) makes usage simpler.

There are a few goals I have with this library:

- Relative simplicity of interface and use, mimicking the STL where possible.
- Decent error messages using a combination of traits and `static_assert`, where possible.
- Insertion and lookup speed. Memory usage is much less of a concern.

A few design considerations up front (I'm happy for these to be criticised):

- Usage of `std::map` and `std::set` over their `unordered` counterparts. This places a smaller burden on the user, in that they don't have to supply a hashing function or specialise `std::hash` for their given type.
- Graphs are segmented by two categories: whether they are directed or undirected, and whether they are weighted or unweighted (that is, if the edges have a weight or not).
- As many algorithms as possible should be free functions to increase reusability.

The parts I've picked out for review correspond to unweighted graphs.

> graph_traits.hpp

```
#ifndef GRAPH_TRAITS_SGL_HPP_ 
#define GRAPH_TRAITS_SGL_HPP_ 

namespace simplegl 
{
namespace graph
{

template <typename Graph>
struct is_weighted;

template <typename Graph>
struct is_directed;

} // end namespace graph
} // end namespace sgl

#endif // GRAPH_TRAITS_SGL_HPP_
```

> graph_base.hpp

```
// Note: This is an internal header file, and shouldn't be imported directly. 

#ifndef GRAPH_BASE_SGL_HPP_
#define GRAPH_BASE_SGL_HPP_

#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

#include "boost/optional.hpp"

namespace simplegl
{
namespace graph
{
namespace detail
{
//Base to utilize for unweighted graphs
template <typename Type, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
struct graph_base
{
    using allocator       = Allocator;
    using reference       = typename allocator::reference;
    using const_reference = typename allocator::const_reference;
    using size_type       = typename allocator::size_type;
    using difference_type = typename allocator::difference_type;
    using pointer         = typename allocator::pointer;
    using const_pointer   = typename allocator::const_pointer;

    using key_type       = Type;                                                    
    using mapped_type    = std::set<Type, Compare, Allocator>;
    using value_type     = std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>;
    using key_compare    = Compare;
    using value_compare  = Compare;
    using base_container = std::map<key_type, mapped_type, key_compare, allocator>;

    using const_iterator         = typename base_container::const_iterator;
    using const_reverse_iterator = typename base_container::const_reverse_iterator;
    using mapped_const_iterator  = typename mapped_type::const_iterator;

    base_container backing_map;
    size_type      num_nodes;
    std::uint64_t  num_edges;

    graph_base()
        : num_nodes(0),
          num_edges(0)
    { }

protected:

    //Disallow usage through a derived pointer, that is, we don't want something
    //like: graph_base<T>* graph = new undirected_graph<T>(). However, we do
    //want to publically inherit member functions from graph_base.
    //The above polymorphic usage will be a compilation error with a protected
    //destructor.
    ~graph_base() { }


public:

    //Convenience constructor to initialize the nodes of a graph.
    template <typename InputIterator>
    graph_base(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        for(InputIterator it = first; it != last; ++it) {
            insert_node(*it);
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    graph_base(std::initializer_list<T> init)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<T, key_type>::value, 
            "Initializer list type must be convertible to Node Type");
        for(auto it = init.begin(); it != init.end(); ++it) {
            insert_node(*it);
        }
    }

    // Number of nodes contained in the graph, |V|
    size_type node_size() const
    {
        return num_nodes;
    }

    // Number of edges in the graph, |E|
    std::uint64_t edge_size() const
    {
        return num_edges;
    }

    // True iff the graph contains at least 1 node
    bool empty() const
    {
        return backing_map.empty();
    }

    //Inserts a completely disconnected node into the graph.
    bool insert_node(const key_type& node)
    {
        auto it = backing_map.find(node);
        if(it == backing_map.end()) {
            backing_map.insert(std::make_pair(node, mapped_type{})); 
            ++num_nodes;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool insert_node(key_type&& node)
    {
        auto n = std::move(node);
        auto it = backing_map.find(n);
        if(it == backing_map.end()) {
            backing_map.insert(std::make_pair(std::move(n), mapped_type{}));
            ++num_nodes;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Returns true if the given node exists in the graph,
    // false otherwise.
    bool exists_node(const key_type& node) const 
    {
        return backing_map.find(node) != backing_map.end();
    }

    //Inserts an edge between from and to, ie, E = E + (from, to)
    //where E is the edge set of the graph.
    bool insert_edge(const key_type& from, const key_type& to)
    {
        auto from_in_nodes = backing_map.find(from);
        auto to_in_nodes = backing_map.find(to);
        auto end = backing_map.end();

        if(from_in_nodes != end && to_in_nodes != end) {
            mapped_type& adj_nodes = from_in_nodes->second;
            adj_nodes.insert(to);
            ++num_edges;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template <typename T> 
    bool insert_edge(const key_type& from, T&& to)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<T, key_type>::value,
            "Edge type must be explicity convertible to Node type");

        auto from_in_nodes = backing_map.find(from);
        auto to_in_nodes = backing_map.find(to);
        auto end = backing_map.end();

        if(from_in_nodes != end && to_in_nodes != end) {
            mapped_type& adj_nodes = from_in_nodes->second;
            adj_nodes.insert(std::forward<T>(to));
            ++num_edges;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    template <typename Iterator>
    void insert_edges(const key_type& from, Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    {
        auto from_it = backing_map.find(from);
        if(from_it != backing_map.end()) {
            for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
                if(backing_map.find(*it) != backing_map.end()) {
                    mapped_type& adj_nodes = from_it->second;
                    adj_nodes.insert(*it);
                    ++num_edges;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Returns true if an edge exists between (from, to), or
    //false otherwise
    bool exists_edge(const key_type& from, const key_type& to) const
    {
        auto mp_it = backing_map.find(from);
        if(mp_it != backing_map.end()) {
            auto it = (mp_it->second).find(to);
            return it != mp_it->second.end();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Removes the edge (from, to).
    bool remove_edge(const key_type& from, const key_type& to)
    {
        auto it = backing_map.find(from);
        if(it != backing_map.end()) {
            mapped_type& adj_nodes = it->second;
            if(adj_nodes.count(to)) {
                adj_nodes.erase(to);
                --num_edges;
                return true;
            }
        }    
        return false;
    }

    template <typename Func, typename... Args>
    auto update_node(key_type&& node, Func f, Args&&... args)
        -> boost::optional<decltype(f(node, args...))>
    {
        using result_type = decltype(f(node, args...));

        auto it = backing_map.find(node);
        if(it != backing_map.end()) {
            auto update(it->first);
            auto result = f(update, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            mapped_type adj_nodes;
            std::swap(adj_nodes, it->second);
            backing_map.erase(it);
            backing_map.insert(std::make_pair(update, std::move(adj_nodes)));

            const auto& adjacent = backing_map.find(update)->second;
            for(auto n = adjacent.begin(); n != adjacent.end(); ++n) {
                mapped_type& m = backing_map.find(*n)->second;
                auto contains = m.find(node);
                if(contains != m.end()) {
                    m.erase(contains);
                    m.insert(update);
                }
            }
            return boost::optional<result_type>(result);
        }
        return boost::optional<result_type>();
    }

    // Returns a const_iterator that can be used to iterator
    // over all nodes contained within the graph.
    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return backing_map.begin();
    }

    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return backing_map.end();
    }

    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const
    {
        return backing_map.rbegin();
    }

    const_reverse_iterator rend() const
    {
        return backing_map.rend();
    }

    const_iterator find_node(const key_type& node) const
    {
        return backing_map.find(node);
    }

    //Calculates the outdegree of a given node, that is,
    //the number of nodes it is adjacent to.
    size_type outdegree(const key_type& node) const
    {
        auto it = backing_map.find(node);
        const mapped_type& s = it->second;
        return s.size();
    }

    //Returns a pair of iterators, pointing to the beginning
    //of the set of adjacent nodes and the end of the set of adjacent
    //nodes respectively.
    std::pair<mapped_const_iterator, mapped_const_iterator> 
    adjacent_nodes(const key_type& node) const
    {
        auto it = backing_map.find(node);
        if(it == backing_map.end()) {
            const mapped_type& begin_s = (backing_map.begin())->second;
            return std::make_pair(begin_s.begin(), begin_s.begin());
        }
        return std::make_pair((it->second).begin(), (it->second).end());
    }
}; //end struct graph_base

} //end namespace detail
} //end namespace graph
} //end namespace simplegl

#endif //GRAPH_BASE_SGL_HPP_
```

> undirected_graph.hpp

```
#ifndef UNDIRECTED_GRAPH_SGL_HPP_
#define UNDIRECTED_GRAPH_SGL_HPP_

#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

#include "graph/graph_traits.hpp"
#include "graph/invariant_exception.hpp"
#include "graph/structure/detail/graph_base.hpp"

namespace simplegl
{
namespace graph
{

//Class defining an undirected, unweighted graph
template <typename Type, 
          typename Compare = std::less<Type>,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<Type>>
class undirected_graph
    : public detail::graph_base<Type, Compare, Allocator>
{
private:

    using base_type = detail::graph_base<Type, Compare, Allocator>;

public:

    using allocator = Allocator;

    using key_type        = typename base_type::key_type; 
    using mapped_type     = typename base_type::mapped_type;
    using value_type      = typename base_type::value_type;
    using key_compare     = typename base_type::key_compare;
    using value_compare   = typename base_type::value_compare;
    using reference       = typename base_type::reference;
    using const_reference = typename base_type::const_reference;
    using pointer         = typename base_type::pointer;
    using const_pointer   = typename base_type::const_pointer;

    using const_iterator           = typename base_type::const_iterator;
    using const_reverse_iterator   = typename base_type::const_reverse_iterator;
    using const_adjacency_iterator = typename base_type::mapped_const_iterator;
    using size_type                = typename base_type::size_type;
    using difference_type          = typename base_type::difference_type;

    using node_type = key_type;

    undirected_graph()
        : base_type()
    { }

    //Convenience constructor to initialize an undirected_graph utilizing
    //any kind of input iterator. 
    template <typename InputIterator>
    undirected_graph(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) 
        : base_type(first, last)
    { }

    template <typename T>
    undirected_graph(std::initializer_list<T> init)
        : base_type(init)
    { }

    //Inserts an edge between from and to, ie, E = E + (from, to).
    //Since this is an undirected graph, an edge is also inserted
    //between to and from. Thus the number of edges in the graph
    //is greater by 2 after insert edge has run.
    bool insert_edge(const Type& from, const Type& to) 
    {
        bool a = base_type::insert_edge(from, to);
        bool b = base_type::insert_edge(to, from);
        if(a != b) {
            throw invariant_exception(
                "Undirected graph invariant broken - directed edge found");
        }
        return a; 
    }

    //Removes the edge (from, to). Because this is an undirected graph,
    //also removes the edge (to, from).
    bool remove_edge(const Type& from, const Type& to) 
    {
        bool a = base_type::remove_edge(from, to);
        bool b = base_type::remove_edge(to, from);
        if(a != b) {
            throw invariant_exception(
                "Undirected graph invariant broken - directed edge found");
        }
        return a;
    }

    //Calculates the indegree of a given node. Since our
    //graph is undirected, every edge adds to both indegree
    //and outdegree, thus indegree(node) == outdegree(node)
    size_type indegree(const Type& node) const
    {
        return base_type::outdegree(node);
    }

    //Removes a given node and any edges associated with it.
    //Returns: the number of edges removed
    size_type remove_node(const Type& node)
    {
        auto node_it = base_type::backing_map.find(node);
        size_type edges_removed = 0;

        //Not in our node set, do nothing.
        if(node_it == base_type::backing_map.end()) {

        }
        //0 indegree, and since it is an undirected_graph, 0 outdegree.
        //Thus it can be directly removed from the map, and we know it
        //will have no edges to remove.
        else if(indegree(node) == 0) {
            edges_removed = node_it->second.size();
            base_type::backing_map.erase(node_it);
            --base_type::num_nodes;
        }
        //General case. Walk through the edge set, removing each
        //edge as we go.
        else {
            mapped_type& edge_set = node_it->second;
            for(auto it = edge_set.begin(); it != edge_set.end(); ++it) {
                remove_edge(node_it->first, *it);
            }
        }

        return edges_removed;
    }

}; //end class undirected_graph

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
struct is_directed<undirected_graph<T, Compare, Allocator>>
  : std::false_type
{ };

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
struct is_weighted<undirected_graph<T, Compare, Allocator>>
  : std::false_type
{ };

} //end namespace graph
} //end namespace simplegl

#endif //UNDIRECTED_GRAPH_SGL_HPP_
```

> directed_graph.hpp

```
#ifndef DIRECTED_GRAPH_SGL_HPP_ 
#define DIRECTED_GRAPH_SGL_HPP_

#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

#include "graph/graph_traits.hpp"
#include "graph/structure/detail/graph_base.hpp"

namespace simplegl
{
namespace graph
{
//Class defining a directed, unweighted graph
template <typename Type, 
          typename Compare = std::less<Type>, 
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<Type>>
class directed_graph
    : public detail::graph_base<Type, Compare, Allocator>
{
private:

    using base_type = detail::graph_base<Type, Compare, Allocator>;

public:

    using allocator = Allocator;

    using key_type        = typename base_type::key_type; 
    using mapped_type     = typename base_type::mapped_type;
    using value_type      = typename base_type::value_type;
    using key_compare     = typename base_type::key_compare;
    using value_compare   = typename base_type::value_compare;
    using reference       = typename base_type::reference;
    using const_reference = typename base_type::const_reference;
    using pointer         = typename base_type::pointer;
    using const_pointer   = typename base_type::const_pointer;

    using const_iterator           = typename base_type::const_iterator;
    using const_reverse_iterator   = typename base_type::const_reverse_iterator;
    using const_adjacency_iterator = typename base_type::mapped_const_iterator;
    using size_type                = typename base_type::size_type;
    using difference_type          = typename base_type::difference_type;

    using node_type = key_type;

private:

    std::map<Type, size_type> indegree_cache;

public:

    directed_graph()
        : base_type()
    { }


    template <typename InputIterator>
    directed_graph(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        for(InputIterator it = first; it != last; ++it) {
            insert_node(*it);
        }
    }

    //Inserts a completely disconnected node into the graph.
    //Thus, the node is added to the keys only. It will only
    //be added to backing_map only when an edge is added between
    //it and another node. Also creates a value in indegree cache for this node.
    bool insert_node(const Type& node)
    {
        bool inserted = base_type::insert_node(node);
        if(inserted) { 
            indegree_cache[node]; 
        }
        return inserted;
    }

    //Inserts an edge between from and to, ie, E = E + (from, to).
    bool insert_edge(const Type& from, const Type& to)
    {
        bool inserted = base_type::insert_edge(from, to);
        if(inserted) {
            ++indegree_cache[to];
        }
        return inserted;
    }

    //Removes the edge (from, to)
    bool remove_edge(const Type& from, const Type& to)
    {
        bool removed = base_type::remove_edge(from, to);
        if(removed) {
            auto old = indegree_cache[to];
            --indegree_cache[to];
            // Make sure nothing overflows
            assert(assert(old - 1) < old);
        }
        return removed;
    }

    size_type indegree(const Type& node) const
    {
        auto it = indegree_cache.find(node);
        if(it == indegree_cache.end()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return it->second;
    }

    //Removes a given node and any edges associated with it.
    //Unfortunately for a directed_graph, this is a relatively
    //expensive operation, depending on indegree. In the best
    //case, it has 0 indegree, hence we can simply remove the
    //node and all the out edges from it, which is an O(log V)
    //operation. However, in the general case, we don't have a list
    //of which nodes have in edges to the given node, 
    //hence it becomes an O(V log E) operation.
    //
    //Returns: the number of edges removed
    size_type remove_node(const Type& node)
    {
        auto node_it = base_type::backing_map.find(node);
        size_type edges_removed = 0;

        //Not in our node set, do nothing.
        if(node_it == base_type::backing_map.end()) {

        }
        //0 indegree, hence directly remove it from the map, subtracting
        //the edges removed from num_edges and the node removed
        //from num_node. This is a bit of a leaky abstraction
        //unfortunately.
        else if(!indegree(node)) {
            edges_removed = node_it->second.size();
            base_type::backing_map.erase(node_it);
            --base_type::num_nodes;
            base_type::num_edges -= edges_removed;
        }
        //General case, must search every node in the map to see if
        //the node we want to remove is in its edge set. 
        else {
            for(auto it = base_type::backing_map.begin(); 
                     it != base_type::backing_map.end();
                     ++it) {

                if(it == node_it) {
                    continue;
                }

                edges_removed += it->second.erase(node_it->first);
            }

            edges_removed += node_it->second.size();
            base_type::backing_map.erase(node_it);
            --base_type::num_nodes;
            base_type::num_edges -= edges_removed;
        }

        return edges_removed;
    }

}; //end class directed_graph

// Trait specializations
template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
struct is_directed<directed_graph<T, Compare, Allocator>>
  : std::true_type
{ };

template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
struct is_weighted<directed_graph<T, Compare, Allocator>>
  : std::false_type
{ };

} //end namespace graph
} //end namespace simplegl

#endif //DIRECTED_GRAPH_SGL_HPP_
```

And that's just about my character limit. In another post I'll throw up some of the generic algorithm code for review as well.

Comment: What is the intended use of this library? Is performance (for scientific computing, say) a major concern? Hash maps kill cache-locality, although since your graph classes are mutable, they'd be hard to replace by arrays.

Comment: @AlexReinking It isn't meant to be a super high performance library. The intended use is as a (relatively) simple to use, "get up and running" graph library. Sure, maps kill cache locality, but creating functional-style immutable graph structures in C++ is a fairly tall order.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then I don't have much to criticize. Also, creating functional graph structures in a functional language is a pretty tall order! ;) Look up "Tying the Knot" sometime...

Comment: It would be nice to have a look at the refactored code. If you released this library, could you put a link to the repo? Thanks.

Comment: @Agostino I've got a repo at https://bitbucket.org/yuushi/sgl. The graph code sits under graph (there's a few other bits and pieces sitting around in the repo as well). I actually haven't touched it for a little while as I've been busy at work, but you're welcome to have a look regardless.

Comment: Thanks, I'm evaluating this for use at work. The license is OK, but the code needs to be robust. Did you find the time to include the suggestions below?

Comment: @Agostino I actually haven't touched it since this question was asked. However, if you're interested, I'm happy to do some more work on it (including finishing up the documentation, which I never quite finished and isn't in the repo). Anyway, this comments section isn't so good for discussing this - feel free to contact me at zaneferrier at gmail dot com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Subtypes names

First of all, I would make sure that the type names in your classes match those in the standard library classes. We can see that some of them differ:

- `allocator` should be `allocator_type`.
- `base_container` should be `container_type`.

## Subtypes correctness

You have something really strange in `graph_base`:

- `using value_type = std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>;`
- `using reference = typename allocator::reference;`

Since you often pass `std::allocator<Type>` as the `Allocator` template parameter, that means that in your class, `reference_type != value_type&` (and it seems that the problem is propagated in the children types). I think that this is never the case in the standard library and I would totally expect `value_type&` and `reference` to be equivalent.

You don't seem to be using `value_type` directly, so I will assume that this is an error that you didn't spot.

From the other `typedef`s, I also assume that you are interested in exposing `Type` to the user of your class and that you don't want it to know that much how your class resembles a mapping type. Therefore, you should change `graph_base::value_type` to:

```
using value_type = Type;
```

## Allocators

In `graph_base` again, this line lind of smells:

```
using base_container = std::map<key_type, mapped_type, key_compare, allocator>;
```

It seems that you are feeding a `std::allocator<Type>` to `std::map` (when you ) which is supposed to allocate `std::pair<const Type, mapped_type>` instances, not `Type` instances. It should be:

```
using base_container = std::map<key_type, mapped_type, key_compare, std::allocator<std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>>>;
```

## Towards a solution?

One way to prevent all this allocator stuff would be to take containers as template parameters, like [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) and let it handle all the allocator-related problems:

```
template <typename Type,
          typename Mapped = std::set<Type>,
          typename Container = std::map<Type, Mapped>>
struct graph_base
{
    // std::map-related types
    using container_type = Container;
    using key_type       = typename container_type::key_type;     
    using mapped_type    = typename container_type::mapped_type;

    // std::set-related types
    using value_type      = Type;
    using allocator_type  = typename Mapped::allocator_type;
    using reference       = typename allocator_type::reference;
    using const_reference = typename allocator_type::const_reference;
    using size_type       = typename allocator_type::size_type;
    using difference_type = typename allocator_type::difference_type;
    using pointer         = typename allocator_type::pointer;
    using const_pointer   = typename allocator_type::const_pointer;

    // ...
};
```

Note that I removed the types `key_compare` and `value_compare`: they weren't used and they prevent users from using an `std::unordered_map` for `Container` since `std::unordered_map` only cares about hasing and equality; it does not care about ordering relations.

Also, from a user perspective, I think that functions taking a `key_type` should rather take a `value_type` instead (as redefined in "Subtypes correctness"): they probably want to use "values of the graph", not "instance of the key type of the hidden underlying map". That would make more sense.

## Exception safety

Your method `insert_edge` in `undirected_graph` does not seem to provide a strong exception guarantee. It may insert one of the edges and not then throw without removing the edge. You should rewrite your code to have the commit-or-rollback guarantee:

```
bool insert_edge(const Type& from, const Type& to) 
{
    // check whether you can safely insert both
    bool a = /* something non-destructive */ ;
    bool b = /* something non-destructive */ ;

    // if there is a problem, throw
    if(a != b) {
        throw invariant_exception(
            "Undirected graph invariant broken - directed edge found");
    }

    // if there is no problem, commit
    base_type::insert_edge(from, to);
    base_type::insert_edge(to, from);
    return a; 
}
```

There may be the same problem in `remove_edge`.

Comment: All good points. I'm not so fussed about `base_container` naming as that doesn't get "hoisted out" of `graph_base` (which is internal and not supposed to be used directly anyway). I do actually use `key_compare` in some of the algorithms. The allocator type was definitely a big oversight, thanks for pointing that out.