# Generic Graph Library Part 2 : Algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, graph

(This is a follow on to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55402/generic-graph-library)).

Having given an implementation for some of the graph structures, here is a portion of the algorithms that are defined to work over them:

> graph_degree.hpp

```
/*! \file graph_degree.hpp
 *  \brief Algorithms relating to node degree.
 *
 *  Defines core algorithms to investigate indegree and 
 *  outdegrees concerning a given graph. This includes finding minimum, 
 *  maximum, average, and the distribution over a whole graph. It also has 
 *  algorithms specifically for finding disonnected nodes (defined as nodes
 *  with 0 indegree, that is, inaccessible nodes), and sink nodes (defined as
 *  nodes with 0 outdegree, that is, nodes one cannot leave). 
 *
 *  \addtogroup graph_algorithm
 *  @{
*/

#ifndef GRAPH_DEGREE_SGL_HPP_
#define GRAPH_DEGREE_SGL_HPP_

#include <functional>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "boost/optional.hpp"

namespace simplegl
{
namespace graph
{

namespace
{

//Since max and min outdegree differ only by the comparator they use,
//and indegree and outdegree differ only by functon call,
//this is the core functionality abstracted out.
template <typename Graph, typename Compare, typename Selector>
boost::optional<
    std::pair<typename Graph::node_type, typename Graph::size_type>
>
find_degree(const Graph& g, Compare comparator, Selector degree_type)
{
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;
    using optional_t = 
        boost::optional<
            std::pair<typename Graph::node_type, typename Graph::size_type>
        >;

    if(g.empty()) { 
        return optional_t();
    }

    auto t = g.begin()->first;
    auto current = degree_type(t);
    auto degree = current;

    auto begin = g.begin();
    std::advance(begin, 1);

    for(auto it = begin; it != g.end(); ++it) {
        current = degree_type(it->first);
        if(comparator(current, degree)) {
            degree = current;
            t = it->first;
        }
    }

    return optional_t(std::make_pair(t, degree));
}

template <typename Graph>
using optional_t = 
    boost::optional<
        std::pair<typename Graph::node_type, typename Graph::size_type>
    >;

template <typename Graph, typename Compare>
optional_t<Graph> find_outdegree(const Graph& g, Compare comparator)
{
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;
    auto select_type = [&](const node_type& n) { return g.outdegree(n); };
    return find_degree(g, comparator, select_type); 
}

template <typename Graph, typename Compare>
optional_t<Graph> find_indegree(const Graph& g, Compare comparator)
{
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;
    auto select_type = [&](const node_type& n) { return g.indegree(n); };
    return find_degree(g, comparator, select_type); 
}

} // end unnamed namespace

/*! \brief Finds the node with maximum outdegree in the Graph g.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \return A std::pair containing the node with maximum outdegree as the first member,
 *          and the degree count as the second member. For graphs with many nodes of equal
 *          maximum degree, it is implementation dependent as to which node is chosen.
*/
template <typename Graph>
optional_t<Graph> max_outdegree(const Graph& g)
{
    using size_type = typename Graph::size_type;
    return find_outdegree(g, std::greater<size_type>());
}

/*! \brief Finds the node with minimum outdegree in the Graph g.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \return A std::pair containing the node with minimum outdegree as the first member,
 *          and the degree count as the second member. For graphs with many nodes of equal
 *          minimum degree, it is implementation dependent as to which node is chosen.
*/
template <typename Graph>
optional_t<Graph> min_outdegree(const Graph& g)
{
    using size_type = typename Graph::size_type;
    return find_outdegree(g, std::less<size_type>());
}

/*! \brief Finds the node with maximum indegree in the Graph g.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \return A std::pair containing the node with maximum indegree as the first member,
 *          and the degree count as the second member. For graphs with many nodes of equal
 *          maximum degree, it is implementation dependent as to which node is chosen.
*/
template <typename Graph>
optional_t<Graph> max_indegree(const Graph& g)
{
    using size_type = typename Graph::size_type;
    return find_indegree(g, std::greater<size_type>());
}

/*! \brief Finds the node with minimum indegree in the Graph g.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \return A std::pair containing the node with minimum indegree as the first member,
 *          and the degree count as the second member. For graphs with many nodes of equal
 *          minimum degree, it is implementation dependent as to which node is chosen.
*/
template <typename Graph>
optional_t<Graph> min_indegree(const Graph& g)
{
    using size_type = typename Graph::size_type;
    return find_indegree(g, std::less<size_type>());
}

/*! \brief Returns the average indegree of all nodes in the graph.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \return A double, represending the average indegree of <B>g</B>.
*/
template <typename Graph>
double average_indegree(const Graph& g)
{
    double start = 0;
    typename Graph::size_type total_nodes = 0;

    for(auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        start += g.indegree(it->first);
        ++total_nodes;
    }

    return start/total_nodes;
}

/*! \brief Returns the average outdegree of all nodes in the graph.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \return A double, represending the average outdegree of <B>g</B>.
*/
template <typename Graph>
double average_outdegree(const Graph& g)
{
    double start = 0;
    typename Graph::size_type total_nodes = 0;

    for(auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        start += g.indegree(it->first);
        ++total_nodes;
    }

    return start/total_nodes;
}

/*! \brief Returns the distribution of outdegrees over of all nodes in the graph.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \return A std::map<typename Graph::size_type, typename Graph::size_type>
 *          containing pairs of type <I>{outdegree : count of nodes with given outdegree}</I>.
*/
template <typename Graph>
std::map<typename Graph::size_type, typename Graph::size_type>
outdegree_distribution(const Graph& g)
{
    std::map<typename Graph::size_type, typename Graph::size_type> mp;
    for(auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        mp[g.outdegree(it->first)] += 1;
    }
    return mp;
}

/*! \brief Returns the distribution of indegrees over of all nodes in the graph.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \return A std::map<typename Graph::size_type, typename Graph::size_type>
 *          containing pairs of type <I>{indegree : count of nodes with given indegree}</I>.
*/
template <typename Graph>
std::map<typename Graph::size_type, typename Graph::size_type>
indegree_distribution(const Graph& g)
{
    std::map<typename Graph::size_type, typename Graph::size_type> mp;
    for(auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        mp[g.indegree(it->first)] += 1;
    }
    return mp;
}

/*! \brief Finds all disconnected nodes of the given graph, inserting them into ii.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \param ii An input iterator into a container that will hold the nodes that are
              found to be disconnected.
 *  \return The number of disconnected nodes found.
*/ 
template <typename Graph, typename Iterator>
std::size_t disconnected_nodes(const Graph& g, Iterator ii)
{
    std::size_t num_disconnected = 0;
    for(auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        if(g.indegree(it->first) == 0) {
            ii = it->first;
            ++num_disconnected;
        }
    }
    return num_disconnected;
}

/*! \brief Finds all sink nodes (nodes with outdegree 0) of the given graph, 
 *         inserting them into ii.
 *  
 *  \param g The graph to search over.
 *  \param ii An input iterator into a container that will hold the nodes that are
              found to be sinks.
 *  \return The number of sink nodes found.
*/ 
template <typename Graph, typename Iterator>
std::size_t sink_nodes(const Graph& g, Iterator ii)
{
    std::size_t num_sink = 0;
    for(auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        if(g.outdegree(it->first) == 0) {
            ii = it->first;
            ++num_sink;
        }
    }
    return num_sink;
}

} //end namespace graph
} //end namespace simplegl

#endif //GRAPH_DEGREE_SGL_HPP_

/*! @} End of Doxygen Group graph_algorithm */
```

> graph_search.hpp

```
/*! \file graph_search.hpp
 *  \brief Algorithms for searching over graphs and finding connected components.
 *
 *  Algorithms to investigate graph connectedness. Contains basic breadth-first 
 *  and depth-first search functionality. In addition, contains tests for
 *  connectedness, finding connected components, and determining whether or
 *  not a graph contains a cycle from a given source node.
 *
 *  \addtogroup graph_algorithm
 *  @{
*/

#ifndef GRAPH_SEARCH_SGL_HPP_
#define GRAPH_SEARCH_SGL_HPP_

#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <stack>

namespace simplegl
{
namespace graph
{

namespace
{
//There are obvious similarities between breadth first and depth first
//searches; in fact, the algorithms are almost identical. To take advantage
//of this, we just need to wrap queue and stack with a begin() function
//which will return a reference to the first element in each. This is required
//because they use different member functions to access the first element,
//that is, front() vs top(). 

template <typename Type>
Type& begin(std::queue<Type>& q)
{
    return q.front();
}

template <typename Type>
Type& begin(std::stack<Type>& s)
{
    return s.top();
}

//Base search, which is used by both DFS and BFS
template <typename Graph, typename Iterator, typename Container>
void search_base
(const Graph& g, const typename Graph::node_type& root, Iterator ii, Container& cont)
{
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;
    using adj_iter  = typename Graph::const_adjacency_iterator;

    std::set<node_type> examined_nodes;

    cont.push(root);
    examined_nodes.insert(root);
    ii = root;

    while(!cont.empty()) {
        node_type current_node = begin(cont);
        cont.pop();
        auto adj_nodes = g.adjacent_nodes(current_node);
        for(auto it = adj_nodes.first; it != adj_nodes.second; ++it) {
            if(examined_nodes.find(*it) == examined_nodes.end()) {
                ii = *it;
                cont.push(*it);
                examined_nodes.insert(*it);
            }
        }
    }
}

} // end unnamed namespace

/*! \brief A standard breadth first search. 
 *  
 *  \param g A graph to search over.
 *  \param root The root node from which to begin the search.
 *  \param ii An insert iterator ii into a container, which will hold all reachable nodes
 *            from <B>root</B>.
 *
*/
template <typename Graph, typename Iterator>
void 
breadth_first_search(const Graph& g, const typename Graph::node_type& root, Iterator ii)
{
    std::queue<typename Graph::node_type> q;
    search_base(g, root, ii, q);
}

/*! \brief A standard depth first search. 
 *  
 *  \param g A graph to search over.
 *  \param root The root node from which to begin the search.
 *  \param ii An insert iterator ii into a container, which will hold all reachable nodes
 *            from <B>root</B>.
 *
*/
template <typename Graph, typename Iterator>
void depth_first_search(const Graph& g, const typename Graph::node_type& root, Iterator ii)
{
    std::stack<typename Graph::node_type> s;
    search_base(g, root, ii, s);
}

/*! \brief Tests two nodes to see if there is a path between them in the given graph. 
 *  
 *  \param g A graph to search over.
 *  \param from The node from which to begin the search.
 *  \param to The node to find a path to.
 *  
 *  \return true if there is a path connecting (from, to), false otherwise.
*/
template <typename Graph>
bool is_connected(const Graph& g, const typename Graph::node_type& from, 
                  const typename Graph::node_type& to)
{
    //Pathological case, if they're the same node, then they must
    //be connected.
    using key_less = typename Graph::key_compare;
    auto comp = key_less();
    if(!(comp(from, to) && !(comp(to, from)))) {
        return true;
    }

    //Otherwise, utilize a BFS. 
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;
    using adj_iter  = typename Graph::const_adjacency_iterator;

    std::queue<node_type> to_examine;
    std::set<node_type> examined_nodes;

    to_examine.push(from);
    examined_nodes.insert(from);

    while(!to_examine.empty()) {
        node_type current_node = to_examine.front();
        to_examine.pop();
        auto adj_nodes = g.adjacent_nodes(current_node);
        for(auto it = adj_nodes.first; it != adj_nodes.second; ++it) {
            if(examined_nodes.find(*it) == examined_nodes.end()) {
                if(*it == to) {
                    return true;
                }
                to_examine.push(*it);
                examined_nodes.insert(*it);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/*! \brief Tests to see if there is a (non-trivial) cyclic path from a given node. 
 *  
 *  \param g A graph to search over.
 *  \param node The node from which to begin the search.
 *  
 *  \return true if there is a cyclic path from <B>node</B> to itself, false otherwise.
*/
template <typename Graph>
bool is_cyclical(const Graph& g, const typename Graph::node_type& node)
{   
    //Utilize a BFS to see if we can get from node back to node
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;
    using adj_iter  = typename Graph::const_adjacency_iterator;

    std::queue<node_type> to_examine;
    std::set<node_type> examined_nodes;

    to_examine.push(node);

    while(!to_examine.empty()) {
        node_type current_node = to_examine.front();
        to_examine.pop();
        auto adj_nodes = g.adjacent_nodes(current_node);
        for(auto it = adj_nodes.first; it != adj_nodes.second; ++it) {
            if(examined_nodes.find(*it) == examined_nodes.end()) {
                if(*it == node) {
                    return true;
                }
                to_examine.push(*it);
                examined_nodes.insert(*it);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/*! \brief Finds all nodes reachable from a given node. Equivalent to running a depth
 *         or bredth-first search on that node. 
 *  
 *  \param g A graph to search over.
 *  \param node The node from which to begin the search.
 *  
 *  \return A std::set containing all the nodes reachable from <B>node</B>.
*/
template <typename Graph>
std::set<typename Graph::node_type> 
connected_component(const Graph& g, const typename Graph::node_type& node)
{
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;
    std::set<node_type> connected;
    std::insert_iterator<std::set<node_type>> ins_it(connected, connected.begin());
    depth_first_search(g, node, ins_it);
    return connected;
}

/*! \brief Finds all connected components of a given graph.
 *  
 *  Connected components partition the graph into equivalence classes based on
 *  reachability. That is, any node in a given connected component is reachable
 *  by any other node in the same connected component, and any node not in that same
 *  connected component is not reachable. 
 *   
 *  \param g A graph to search over.
 *  
 *  \return A std::set of std::sets, each consisting of one connected component.
*/
template <typename Graph>
std::set<std::set<typename Graph::node_type>> 
all_connected_components(const Graph& g)
{
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;
    std::set<std::set<node_type>> cc;
    bool found = false;

    for(auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        for(auto cc_subset = cc.begin(); cc_subset != cc.end(); ++cc_subset) {
            if(cc_subset->find(it->first) != cc_subset->end()) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {
            cc.insert(connected_component(g,it->first));
        }
        found = false;
    }
    return cc;
}

/*! \brief Determines if the graph is fully connected.
 *  
 *  A fully connected graph is one in which there is a path from any node
 *  to any other node.
 *   
 *  \param g A graph to search over.
 *  
 *  \return true if the graph is full connected, false otherwise.
*/
template <typename Graph>
bool is_fully_connected(const Graph& g)
{
    auto s = all_connected_components(g);
    return s.size() == 1;
}

} //end namespace graph
} //end namespace simplegl

#endif //GRAPH_SEARCH_SGL_HPP_

/*! @} End of Doxygen Group graph_algorithm */
```

> topological_sort.hpp

```
#ifndef TOPOLOGICAL_SORT_SGL_HPP_
#define TOPOLOGICAL_SORT_SGL_HPP_

#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

#include "graph/graph_traits.hpp"

namespace simplegl
{
namespace graph
{

// Returns true iff the given graph can be topologically sorted,
// false otherwise.
template <typename Graph>
bool is_topologically_sortable(const Graph& g)
{
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;

    if(!is_directed<Graph>::value) { return false; }

    Graph possible_dag(g); 
    std::deque<node_type> zero_degree;

    for(auto it = possible_dag.begin(); it != possible_dag.end(); ++it) {
        if(possible_dag.indegree(it->first) == 0) {
            zero_degree.push_back(it->first);
        }
    }

    while(!zero_degree.empty()) {
        node_type& w = zero_degree.front();
        auto adjacent = possible_dag.adjacent_nodes(w);
        for(auto it = adjacent.first; it != adjacent.second; ++it) {
            possible_dag.remove_edge(w, *it);
            if(possible_dag.indegree(*it) == 0) {
                zero_degree.push_back(*it);
            }
        }
        zero_degree.pop_front();
    }

    return possible_dag.edge_size() == 0;
}

// Topologically sorts the given graph, if possible.
// Returns a std::deque containing the topological sorting, if 
// it exists, or an empty deque otherwise.
template <typename Graph>
std::deque<typename Graph::node_type> topologically_sort(const Graph& g)
{
    using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;

    if(!is_directed<Graph>::value) { return std::deque<node_type>(); }

    Graph possible_dag(g); 
    std::deque<node_type> zero_degree;
    std::deque<node_type> sorted;

    for(auto it = possible_dag.begin(); it != possible_dag.end(); ++it) {
        if(possible_dag.indegree(it->first) == 0) {
            zero_degree.push_back(it->first);
        }
    }

    while(!zero_degree.empty()) {
        node_type& w = zero_degree.front();
        sorted.push_back(w);
        auto adjacent = possible_dag.adjacent_nodes(w);
        for(auto it = adjacent.first; it != adjacent.second; ++it) {
            possible_dag.remove_edge(w, *it);
            if(possible_dag.indegree(*it) == 0) {
                zero_degree.push_back(*it);
            }
        }
        zero_degree.pop_front();
    }

    if(possible_dag.edge_size() == 0) {
        return sorted;
    }

    return std::deque<node_type>();
}

} // end namespace graph
} // end namespace simplegl

#endif // TOPOLOGICAL_SORT_SGL_HPP_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several places where you could improve the readability of your code:

- First of all, you also use iterator-based `for` loops while you could use range-based `for` loop instead. Consider this function:

  ```
  template <typename Graph>
  double average_indegree(const Graph& g)
  {
      double start = 0;
      typename Graph::size_type total_nodes = 0;

      for(auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
          start += g.indegree(it->first);
          ++total_nodes;
      }

      return start/total_nodes;
  }
  ```

  With a range-based `for` loop, it becomes:

  ```
  template <typename Graph>
  double average_indegree(const Graph& g)
  {
      double start = 0;
      typename Graph::size_type total_nodes = 0;

      for(auto& elem: g) {
          start += g.indegree(elem.first);
          ++total_nodes;
      }

      return start/total_nodes;
  }
  ```
- You can simplify some `return` statements thanks to [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) by not typing the return type a second time. You can rewrite `find_degree` this way:

  ```
  template <typename Graph, typename Compare, typename Selector>
  boost::optional<
      std::pair<typename Graph::node_type, typename Graph::size_type>
  >
  find_degree(const Graph& g, Compare comparator, Selector degree_type)
  {
      using node_type = typename Graph::node_type;

      if(g.empty()) { 
          return {};
      }

      auto t = g.begin()->first;
      auto current = degree_type(t);
      auto degree = current;

      auto begin = g.begin();
      std::advance(begin, 1);

      for(auto it = begin; it != g.end(); ++it) {
          current = degree_type(it->first);
          if(comparator(current, degree)) {
              degree = current;
              t = it->first;
          }
      }

      return { std::make_pair(t, degree) };
  }
  ```
- Instead of writing `= 0` to zero-initialize an "unknown" type, you can use the new syntax for [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (4th syntax in the given link):

  ```
  template <typename Graph>
  double average_indegree(const Graph& g)
  {
      double start = 0.0;
      typename Graph::size_type total_nodes{};

      for(auto& elem: g) {
          start += g.indegree(elem.first);
          ++total_nodes;
      }

      return start/total_nodes;
  }
  ```

You can also give more power to the user:

- In `average_indegree`, you fixed the return type to `double`. You cuold have your function take a `ReturnType` template parameter defaulted to `double` instead:

  ```
  template <typename Graph
            typename ReturnType = double>
  ReturnType average_indegree(const Graph& g)
  {
      ReturnType start{};
      typename Graph::size_type total_nodes{};

      for(auto& elem: g) {
          start += g.indegree(elem.first);
          ++total_nodes;
      }

      return start/total_nodes;
  }
  ```

  Note that if you choose an `int` type smaller than `Graph::size_type`, the result type may be too small to contain the actual result. You could change the return type to `typename std::common_type<ReturnType, typename Graph::size_type>::type` to ensure that a big enough return type will be picked.

I still have some remarks about the names of your functions:

- I am not very fond of the function `begin` to take the first element of a collection. `begin` is already widely used in the standard library to take an *iterator* to the first element. While the function in itself may be fine, I would change its name to `first` or something akin. That would also prevent potential name clashes with [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) if somebody likes to use some bad old `using namespace` in their code.